# how to achieve this in mysql/mariadb - Order and Sorting

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

```
---------------------------
|Status  |Application Date|
|New     |2019-01-02      |
|New     |2019-01-01      |
|Updated |2019-01-15      |
|Deleted |2019-01-20      |
|Updated |2019-01-16      |
---------------------------

1. Sort in-order from New,Updated, and Deleted
 a. Sort by New ASC - to see the first entry for first come first serve
 b. Sort by Updated Desc - to see the latest update first
 c. Sort by Deleted Desc - see the latest deleted
```

I have tried 3 query and union but you can order them together not per query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this logic:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    FIELD(Status, 'New', 'Updated', 'Deleted'),
    CASE WHEN Status = 'New' THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(app_date) ELSE -1.0*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(app_date) END;
```

The first level of sorting places new records before updated records, and updated records before deleted records.  The second level sorts ascending on the date for new records, and descending for all others.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But this will not work since there are old data that needs to be sorted.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  What about my answer is not working for you?

Comment: Sorry about that but. It is correct and working as expected. thank you